# java.util.logging assign logger to a specific package

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I implemented two customized handler to log information on DB and an additional flat file (DBHandler and MyFileHandler). This new log handlers will be used by a single class on a specific package.
I attached the two new loggers to a specific package only.
The idea is to switch between this two handlers (file and database)for the classes contaiend on a specific package, but currently with the current configuration I could not do that, so either I am logging with both handler either there is no log at all.
I tried to set the log level for DB handler to off but it is still logging normally on DB.

below the configuration file is use logging.properties

```
############################################################
#####   Global properties
############################################################

handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, com.test.logging.DBHandler, com.test.logging.MyFileHandler

.level = INFO

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %t/CLog%g.log
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

    com.test.logging.MyFileHandler.level = ALL
    com.test.logging.MyFileHandler.pattern = %t/custLog%g.log
    com.test.logging.MyFileHandler.limit = 50000
    com.test.logging.MyFileHandler.count = 1
    com.test.logging.MyFileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

    com.test.logging.DBHandler.level=OFF

    com.test.ccb.mon.handlers=com.test.logging.DBHandler, com.test.logging.MyFileHandler
```

The class using the logger to track he inforamtion is below

```
package com.test.ccb.mon;
    public class Utils {

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getCanonicalName());

public void logging()
{

 //processing
   logger.info("message);

}
```

}

DBHandler class:

```
public class DBHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {

    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {


    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord logRecord) {
        if (isLoggable(logRecord))
        {

            try {
                      //SQL call to insert onDB
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

MyFileHandler class:

```
public class MyFileHandler extends FileHandler{

        public MyileHandler() throws IOException, SecurityException {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
            super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            super.flush();

        }

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {
            super.publish(record);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you load your logging.properties file, for example with a call to the `LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration()` method?

Comment: _How_ do you want to switch between your handlers? Through a configuration parameter? Programatically?

Comment: @LittleSanti i want to switch if possible between two log method according the needs
db logging only 
com.test.ccb.mon.handlers=DBHandler
or flat file logging only 
com.test.ccb.mon.handlers=MyFileHandler
or both on the same time 
com.test.ccb.mon.handlers=DBHandler,MyFileHandler

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn de Bruijn  yes the file is loaded correctly, just i need to log my package on a DB or Flat file according to the need.

Comment: Can you add your implementation of the `DBHandler` class to your question? I think the implementation of the `publish` method should check the level; this could be the cause of seeing messages while the level is `OFF`.

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn handlers classes added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Handler class doesn't read any properties from the LogManager by default.  You have to code that logic in all of your subclasses.

```
public class DBHandler extends Handler {

    public DBHandler() {
        LogManager m = LogManager.getLogManager();
        String p = getClass().getName();
        String v = m.getProperty(p + ".level");
        try {
            if (v != null) {
                super.setLevel(Level.parse(v));
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            reportError(v, re, ErrorManager.OPEN_FAILURE);
        }
        //@todo create code to parse filter, formatter, encoding, etc.
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord logRecord) {
        if (isLoggable(logRecord)) {
            try {
                //SQL call to insert onDB
            } catch (Exception e) {
                reportError("", e, ErrorManager.WRITE_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reproducing your problem is not so easy for me. With handler classes similar to yours, changes to the configuration file have the expected effect. With the `DBHandler.level=OFF` setting, the database handler output is missing for me:

```
Aug 11, 2015 1:47:26 PM com.test.ccb.mon.Utils logging
DBHandler.publish - handler level: OFF; log record level: INFO
INFO: message
MyFileHandler - message

Logging handlers:
###java.util.logging.FileHandler-ALL
###java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler-ALL
###com.test.logging.DBHandler-OFF
###com.test.logging.MyFileHandler-ALL
```

**Your debug code to print the logging handlers is now also included in the following `main` method to your `Utils` class. You could run this method yourself, to see whether this way of reading the configuration file works better for you:**

```
public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws IOException
{
    final String fileName = "logging.properties";
    final InputStream propertiesStream = Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    //final InputStream propertiesStream = new FileInputStream("path to file");
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(propertiesStream);

    new Utils().logging();
    System.out.println();

    // No handlers for this logger directly, but four for its parent.
    System.out.println("Logging handlers:");
    for (final Handler handler : logger.getParent().getHandlers())
        System.out.println("###" + handler.getClass().getName()
                           + "-" + handler.getLevel());
}
```

A very simple version of your `DBHandler` class could look like this (please note the `if (isLoggable(record))` check in the `publish` method):

```
package com.test.logging;

import java.util.logging.*;

/**
 * Logging handler that stores logging in the database.
 */
public class DBHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void publish(final LogRecord record) {
        System.out.println("DBHandler.publish - handler level: " + getLevel()
                           + "; log record level: " + record.getLevel());
        if (isLoggable(record))
            System.out.println(getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + record.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        // Empty.
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        // Empty.
    }
}
```

Comment: de burgin added a trace for the log level for DBHandler somehow it is receiving INFO level wich is correct. but somehow the logger still sending the message to the DB

Comment: See changes to example output and code for a possible debug statement that print both log levels.

Comment: i did some debugging using the below code to read the level used by the handler, for DBHandler it is always returning "ALL" regardless of the supplied level on the config file.


  Handler[] tab=logger.getHandlers();
     for (int i=0;i<tab.length;i++)
      System.out.println("###"+tab[i].getClass().getName()+"-"+tab[i].getLevel().getName());

###com.test.logging.MyFileHandler-SEVERE
###com.test.logging.DBHandler-ALL

probably there is an issue with the file itself